# Can I see what strangers are using my freenet for

Tags: networking, encryption, p2p, freenet

I understand that Freenet achieves plausible deniability by using nodes to pass on data to other nodes even if they have no connection to the file being transferred. My question is, if I am running Freenet but not browsing, is there any way for me to see what files other are using my computer to store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from "About Freenet" and bolded items are quoted and is your answer:

> Users contribute to the network by giving bandwidth and a portion of their hard drive (called the "data store") for storing files. Files are automatically kept or deleted depending on how popular they are, with the least popular being discarded to make way for newer or more popular content. **Files are encrypted, so generally the user cannot easily discover what is in his datastore, and hopefully can't be held accountable for it.** Chat forums, websites, and search functionality, are all built on top of this distributed data store.

Taken from https://freenetproject.org/whatis.html

Of course you can always try to decrypt those files. It existed somewhere on your computer. Good luck decrypting them.

Comment: Can I at least see the names of the files so I can search for the keys? I'm just really curious what people are doing with my bandwidth.

Comment: Freenet was designed to make that impossible.

Comment: @user85686 As I mentioned, the files existed on your PC. If you know what you are looking for, and know how to decrypt files, then yes you probably can see them. But both the filename, and content of the files will be encrypted (my current guess as I haven't used Freenet before) so you might find a folder full of encrypted text/filenames but thats it.

Comment: "If you know what you are looking for" is the important part. Freenet URIs (addresses) generally consist of two parts – the routing key, and the encryption key. (The actual filename is usually included, but is of little importance.) When your node stores a file, it only knows its routing key, and there is no way of decrypting the contents unless you obtain the full URI from elsewhere. This is an important part of Freenet's "plausible deniability".

Comment: Well how can I see the routing keys then? And if I would get the full URI, and try to download it, would Freenet tell me I already have the file?

Comment: @user85686 What you are attempting seems to crack on Freenet encryption and how it works. Probably best if you start reading on Freenet documentation to see exactly how it works and maybe go through the source code to learn exactly how it works, and maybe by then you can figure out how to see the routing keys. If you managed to get the full URI, means you have both encryption and routing key, it will probably locate the file on your PC, decrypt it, and present the file to you in plaintext (or whatever the file original format before encryption).

Answer (score 1):

The Freenet architecture does not store whole files with a single users datastore, only parts of the file.   This is due to Freenet being a distributed network.